# How to change graph formatting options with TI-Basic on TI-84?

Tags: ti-basic

I'm trying to make a simple program on my TI-84 Plus.

It graphs cool lines one at a time. But some of the lines would look much better if I could change window values and remove the axes (2nd > Format > AxesOff), but I don't know how to do this.

Here is the program so far:

```
PROGRAM: TEST2
:"10sin(1/X)" -> Y1
:DispGraph
:"tan(X)" -> Y1
:DispGraph
```

Can DispGraph take extra parameters that can change Windows values? Is there any function that can do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can insert those "AxesOff" and other graphing commands such as zooming directly into the program by being in the program editing mode and just going to them like normal. As for window size, you use the Window vars located under Vars -> Window. Saying something like 1->Xmin will set the Xmin value of the graph to 1.